# How to add HTTP header to MicroShedTest and SharedContainerConfig JUnit tests

Tags: integration-testing, junit5, payara, payara-micro

I have integration tests that have been running smoothly until I added security to my application. The security uses a custom generated api key and validation is done in a custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism from header 'X-API-Key'.

I need to find out if it is possible to add headers to calls made by the test suite. I have checked the internet and all I found was `@BasicAuthConfig` and `@JwtConfig` which was not of any use.

I need to added a header 'X-API-Key' to http calls made to the containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find anything useful so I created my own solution. Instead of relying on `@RESTClient` to give me the resource proxy I created my own like so:

```
public static <T> T getResourceProxy(Class<T> t) {
    Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
    headerMap.put("X-API-Key", "abcdefg.abcdefg1234567hij890");
    headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headerMap.put("Accept", "application/json, text/plain");

    JAXRSClientFactoryBean bean = new JAXRSClientFactoryBean();
    bean.setHeaders(headerMap);
    bean.setResourceClass(t);
    bean.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/myApp");

    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();

    providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    providers.add(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    bean.setProviders(providers);

    return bean.create(t);
}
```